# Expect never matches the pattern

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, expect

I am trying to write a script that will enter the password automatically, however it seems like that the expect never matches the pattern.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect --

set pass "test"
set timeout 5

spawn sudo ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa StrictHostKeyChecking=no vongrad@localhost

expect {
  timeout { send_user "\nFailed to get password prompt\n"; exit 1 }
  "*ssword*" {
    send "$pass\r"
  }
}
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: as no one has offered an opinion on your original question, are you sure that expect uses shell wild cards like '*'. rather than true regular experssions, which would be done as `.*ssword.*`. Try that. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a key (without a password) for logging in instead of a password you write in a script? That way you avoid being promped for passwords by ssh.
For example as described here: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/

Comment: This is just a part of the code I am writing, whole script will be based on expect and send. Therefor I have to find a way  how to do it...

Comment: But why use a password for logging in?